# ¿Cómo gestiona git los cambios realizados por distintas personas en la misma rama?

Tags: git, git-commit, ramas-git

Supongamos que un equipo trabaja sobre la misma branch (una copia de main), y digamos que se realizan 3 commits diferentes (de diferentes integrantes).

Al aceptar el pull request de estos 3, ¿se sobreescribe toda la branch main? ¿o solo se agregan a main los cambios (lineas de código) realizados en diferentes archivos (suponiendo que cada persona modificó diferentes archivos)?

Principalmente me gustaría saber cómo evitar que se sobreescriba toda la branch main para no descartar los cambios realizados en caso de que varios trabajen a la vez sobre la misma branch copia.

Comment: Si los tres integrantes tienen permiso para escribir en el mismo repositorio, no hay pull requests, sino que cada integrante hará un push que irá a la rama main. Los restantes integrantes deben hacer pull para recibir esos cambios (que se mezclan con los suyos propios) antes de intentar hacer su correspondiente push (que los demás deberán bajarse también con pull para mezclarlo, etc.) Cada una de esas mezclas modifica los ficheros necesarios solamente. No sé qué entiendes por "sobreescribir toda la branch". En el fondo se trata de que al final los tres acaben con el mismo resultado.

Comment: Es decir, una vez los tres han hecho su correspondiente push (y los pull necesarios para recibir los cambios realizados por los demás), los tres finalizarán en el mismo estado, tanto de su carpeta de trabajo, como de la lista de commits que verán en la rama main. Todos los commits previos a este intercambio de push/pull obviamente seguirán como estaban, y simpemente se habrán añadido encima nuevos commits (algunos de ellos serían commits de tipo "merge" que integran los cambios de los otros commit)

Comment: Entonces básicamente hay que tener un orden para ir aplicando los cambios al main, no? para que el siguiente trabaje sobre esos cambios, y no trabaje con versiones que no tienen el cambio de los anteriores, es lo que entiendo.

Comment: Sí, eso es. De hecho si alguien ha hecho un push al repositorio remoto, no te dejará a tí hacer push de tus propios commit hasta que no hayas hecho antes un pull para recibir los cambios e integrarlos con los tuyos. Después de eso ya podrás hacer push de la versión "mezclada" (siempre que no se te adelante otro y haga push antes! por eso es importante coordinarse un poco)

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo en la pregunta un commit + push con "pull request". Si están todos trabajando en la misma rama, no habrá pull requests o merges

Comment: Gracias @abulafia, era lo que quería saber, saludos.